# Google Cloud SQL Connection/Permission Failures

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, mysql-workbench, google-cloud-sql

Having trouble with the final steps of this wordpress launcher [guide from google](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project).

I've built my page on the localhost and happily pressed "deploy" then eagerly waited for my little bird to fly.  Imagine my chagrine when it feel lame, unable to connect reach it's friend, the google cloud sql servers.

First I tried to fix it by using the command [supplied by google here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-client#othermysqlprog):

> mysql --host=instance-IP --user=user-name --password

But I was greeted with only

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '--host=ip --user=name --pass' at line 1

I tried a number of different versions to no avail. I searched the forums which suggested using mySQL workbench, a tool with which I am familiar.

Here too I was met with numerous errors.

> Failed to Connect to MySQL at 2601:4:2d80:a6f:10ff:c984:174e:f135  :0 with user root

Both for reasons (0)

and for reasons (2)

> Unknown MySQL server host 'ip-address' (2)

Error 0 is supposed to be, according to google:

> If Google Cloud SQL rejects the connection, for example, because the IP address your client is connecting from is not authorized, [this will be the] error you receive

That doesn't make sense because I've a) given them my ip and b) there currently is no password (cleared it out while trying to figure out what could be wrong).

Basically I'm at my wits end.  I've looked around fairly extensively (I've spent the last 6 hours trying to fix this) and can't get what seems like it should be something fairly simple to work.

Basically what I'm saying is: help me stack overflow, you're my apps only hope.

thanks.

Comment: have you given your instance an IP and then tried connecting to *that*?

Comment: you mean via the cloud sql access control? yes. same lost connection (0) error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, final solution! basically after so many attempts I isolated it down to being that the cloud sql wasn't accepting my ip address.

This narrowed my thinking to a) I hadn't entered the correct ip address (logical), or b) I was behind a proxy and didn't know it.

I ran ipconfig and then entered every possible ip from that, as well as the standard "what is my ip" google search and entered that as well.  No dice.  This lead me back to option b) firewall or proxy.  I searched "am I behind a proxy"? which lead me to [link](http://amibehindaproxy.com/).

This returned a *different* IPv4 than the google "what is my ip" address, I entered that and *success*! it worked.  Why this different ip address worked where the google search and ipconfig search did not is beyond me, so anyone chiming in here about why/where to find it consistently are very welcome.

Comment: My issue was related to accessing a couldsql-proxy pod from others, the solution was: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/issues/35#issuecomment-218637183